# How to create an output for Hackerrank in R?

Tags: r

I've been attempting the Fizzbuzz question on Hackerrank. I am able to run my code correctly in R, but am getting error messages on Hackerrank.

What is missing from my code below?

```
fizzBuzz <- function(n) {

set= seq.int(1,n,1)
stdin2=c(NA, n)
for (i in 1:length(set)){

     stdin2[i]= ifelse((set[i] %% 15)==0, "FizzBuzz", 
     ifelse((set[i] %% 3)==0 & (set[i] %% 5)!=0, "Fizz",
     ifelse((set[i] %% 5)==0 & (set[i] %% 3)!=0, "Buzz", i)))
     }
  write(cat(stdin2, "\n"), stdout())
 }
```

I am including stdout() within the write function at the end. A little confused on how I can make the above work- so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `cat(...)` returns `NULL`, so `write(..., stdout())` is useless.

Comment: Other programming languages mandate a `for` loop, some penalize vectorized ops *a little*, R tends to to vector ops very efficiently (often much faster than `for` loops). Consider vectorizing things and return a whole vector at once (which by-default handles the "print" requirement). On this theme, you can remove the `for` portion and change all `set[i]` to `set`, and it'll still work.

Comment: Next step: your logic is too intensive: if you get past the first level of `ifelse` (15) into "false", then you don't need `(set[i]%%5)!=0`, as it is guaranteed at that point; similar to the next conditional.

Comment: (BTW: I have it in 86 chars, a score of 11.4 on that assuming `(200-nch)/10` ... R doesn't make it easy to do a lot better, haven't found one that scores better per code-golf, though I'm sure somebody can find an improvement.)